# Envelope address printing software

Tags: windows, printing

I need to send about 1000 letters to my customers and I need to print the envelopes. I have addresses of my customers. I need a software that prints those addresses to the envelope with my logo and a return address.

Most of the freeware software have envelope size limitations. So, I prefer a paid pro software which supports custom sizes. I have Windows 10 OS. Can someone please recommend me some software?

I found this software called [*Labels & Addresses*](https://www.belightsoft.com/products/labelsaddresses/) is good, but it's only for Mac OS users :(

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the output that you expect with all the specified requirements?

Comment: Use your preferred document editor.. you just need to experiment with the printer and the positioning of the text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Mail Merge feature of Microsoft Word to achieve this. See [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-mail-merge-to-personalize-letters-d7686bb1-3077-4af3-926b-8c825e9505a3) page to understand how to do so.

There are many envelope templates available online. You dont have to design the envelope yourself. Download the one that you like and continue with the procedure.

Comment: MS word mailmerg is crazy, if I set margins to 0 still it prints like it still have margins, and if you accidentally click print button, instead of "Finish and merge --> print documents, it just resets to the settings in "print dialog box" and it doesn't print the orientaion correctly, if I choose print mode as landscape via "mailings" tab, it just prints to the "portrait" .. I think MS word, stores 2 kinds of settings for the same document .. crazy ...

Comment: and if you change the layout via "start mailmerge --> envelopes" it just asks you to open the changed document as a brand new document, crazy .. and when it does open, it looses some of the parts (business logo etc) .. crazy .. The word is meant to print other documents it does it well, but, printing envelopes is not it's main job, so it sucks at it. Please suggest me another software please.